# Configuring Apache 2 with mod_wsgi for Django - no httpd.conf file

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am using Apache 2 on raspbian os. I read somewhere that in the newest versions of Apache there is no httpd.conf file, is this true? **[Edit]** (This is true)

My apache server is running (I can see the default web page), and mod_wsgi is successfully installed. So I began the instructions [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for using django 1.5 with apache. However it tells me I need to add the following lines to the httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

However, there is no httpd.conf file present in my version of apache. I have checked `/etc/httpd/conf`and `/etc/apache2` for the http.conf file. `/etc/apache2` **is** where apache is though.

In short, where should I add the required settings so that apache recognizes mod_wsgi.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from running 'apache2 -V'. One of the things output should be something like SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, many distros use

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Instead. However you shouldn't really edit that and it affects apache2 globally, i.e. all you sites (virtual-hosts). If you have only the one site better edit the contents of:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

The Ubuntu Apache2 configuration documentation is a good getting started guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/httpd.html#http-configuration

Here is tutorial configuring Apache2 with mod_wsgi for Django on Ubuntu 11.04 wihtout httpd.conf: http://blog.madspace.me/configure-python-django-with-apache/, and one on 12.04: http://www.lennu.net/2012/05/14/django-deployement-installation-to-ubuntu-12-dot-04-server/

Comment: I just wanted to come back confirm that this is the correct way to configure apache.  I first started editing apache2.conf, but as more sites were added, it was much easier to edit the specific settings for each virtual-host

Comment: to confirm, config instructions for http.conf can be applied to apache2.conf if the former DNE? for instance, inserting a line like `WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py`